# awk script replace value with increment with if

Tags: text-processing, awk, scripting

I have a pipe delimted file

```
d1000|1000
d1001|100
d1002|10
d1003|1
d1004|
d1005|
```

I want to modify $2 if length is less than 4 digits, and also keep empty spaces as is

so trying to do it via awk script

```
BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="\t" }

{
n=1100
{ if (length($2)!=4 && length($2)>0) {$2=++n}};

print $1, $2
}
```

but it's printing same number over & over

```
d1000   1000
d1001   1101
d1002   1101
d1003   1101
d1004
d1005
```

whereas desired output

```
d1000   1000
d1001   1101
d1002   1102
d1003   1103
d1004
d1005
```

---

EDIT: here is the above code formatted legibly by `gawk -o-`:

```
BEGIN {
        FS = "|"
        OFS = "\t"
}

{
        n = 1100
        if (length($2) != 4 && length($2) > 0) {
                $2 = ++n
        }
        print $1, $2
}
```

Comment: It's important to format your code properly in any programming language for your own sake and for the sake of anyone else trying to understand it. I edited your question to show one way you could format awk code legibly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error may be obvious with more consistent indentation:

```
BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="\t" }
{
  n=1100
  {
    if (length($2)!=4 && length($2)>0) {
      $2=++n
    }
  };
  print $1, $2
}
```

Everything inside the outer braces gets executed, unconditionally, for each record - so the value of `n` is reset every line.

You should move the initialization of `n` to the `BEGIN` block:

```
BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="\t"; n=1100 }
{
  {
    if (length($2)!=4 && length($2)>0) {
      $2=++n
    }
  };
  print $1, $2
}
```

or (more idiomatically)

```
BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="\t"; n=1100 }
(length($2)!=4 && length($2)>0) {
  $2=++n
}
{
  print $1, $2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose this solution:

```bsh
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='\t' '$2 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}$/ { $2 = 1100 +(++c) } { print $1,$2 }' file 
d1000   1000
d1001   1101
d1002   1102
d1003   1103
d1004
d1005
```